# How can I synchronize accessing a global var across two external JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, prototype, synchronize

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "./test1.js"></script>
        <script src = "./test2.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

test1.js

```
var a;
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        a=10;   
    },1000);
});
```

test2.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Busy waiting... doesn't Work.
    /*while(typeof(a) === "undefined"){
        console.log(a);
    };*/
    console.log(a);
});
```

test2 prints 'a' is 'undefined'...
How can I synchronize 'a' over two javascript files?

Comment: `while(typeof(a) === "undefined"){ console.log(a); };` is never a good idea. It will block the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason busy-waiting didn't work is that JavaScript on browsers has only one *main* thread, so the busy-wait was preventing the code from `test1.js` from ever running. Busy-waiting is almost never a good idea in general, and essentially never a good idea in browser-based JavaScript. :-)

Ideally, the two files would provide an intentional way to synchronize between them.

But if there is no event that `test2.js` can use, and if it's definitely correct to wait until `a` has a value other than `undefined`, you can use a `setTimeout` loop:

`test2.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkForA() {
        if (typeof a === "undefined") {
            // Keep waiting
            setTimeout(checkForA, 10); // 50 = 50 milliseconds
        } else {
            // Got it
            console.log(a);
        }
    }

    checkForA();
});
```

If it's possible to avoid this timeout loop by using some kind of notification from `test1.js`, that would be better; but in the worst case, polling every 50ms or so isn't a big deal. It may be a good idea to have it give up at some point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var started = Date.now();

    function checkForA() {
        if (typeof a === "undefined") {
            // Still don't have it, keep waiting?
            if (Date.now() - start > 10000) { // More than 10 seconds
                // Give up
                console.log("Gave up waiting for a");
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkForA, 10); // 50 = 50 milliseconds
            }
        } else {
            // Got it
            console.log(a);
        }
    }

    checkForA();
});
```

Comment: I would expect a to be defined but null if test1.js is loaded before test2.js

Comment: @mplungjan, `var a;` will create a `undefined` variable isn't it ? In this particular example, value of `a` will never be `null`

Comment: Ah. Right. I never use un-initialised vars

Comment: @mplungjan: If `test1.js` is loaded before `test2.js`, `a` will exist but have the value `undefined` until `test1.js`'s ready handler fires. If `test2.js` is loaded before `test1.js`, `a` won't exist at all until it's loaded (of course), but `typeof a` won't throw an error; we get `"undefined"` in both cases.

Comment: Thank you! 
But... is there any way to bind variable changes dynamically in javascript??

Comment: @frebern: There is no event raised when a variable's value is changed, no. If you're the one defining the variable, you could make it an object property instead and define it with a *setter*, which is a function that gets called when a value is assigned to the property. In ES2015 there are also `Proxy` objects, which can get involved in an object's property resolution, which is handy when you're not the one defining the object. (But it's new, so browser support is an issue.) But not for variables.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `$(document).ready(function(){` with `$(window).load(function(){` or you can use js `window.load=function(){`. this will waiting for all html,css and js to load then execute script code in that function.

Comment: I already tried 'ready' test1.js and 'load' test2.js(below answer) but it was not worked...